# Finding the ancestral nodes of a tree created with a simple geometric progression

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm looking for an algorithm that will give me the ancestral line for any node in any tree that has been created using a geometric series where `a = 1`, and `r` equals any whole number. For example the tree in the image below, `r = 2`, and the ancestral line for `26` is `[26, 13, 6, 3, 1]`.

[image]

I've had a go at this myself and have come up with an answer that appears to give me the correct answer for the values of `r` that I've tried. But before I create an app that uses this algorithm to provide file-system resources I want to be sure that I'm not missing some edge-case somewhere. It feels like the kind of problem that must have an established solution that is almost certainly more elegant that mine. Does anyone know of anything?

```
# My python implementation.

import math

def findLevelOfFolder(folder):
    """ Find the 'level' on which a given folder sits.  """
    if folder == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        level = 2
        while True:
            lower, upper= boundsOfLevel(level)
            if folder >= lower and folder <= upper:
                return level
            level += 1


def sumOfProgression(r, upToAndIncludingTerm):
    """
    Sums a simple geometric series.

    If r = 2, and upToAndIncludingTerm = 6, we'refinding the value of...
    pow(2, 0) + pow(2, 1) + pow(2, 3) + ... + pow(2, 5)
    """
    rRepeated = [r] * upToAndIncludingTerm
    powers = range(0, upToAndIncludingTerm)

    return sum(map(pow, rRepeated, powers))


def boundsOfLevel(level):
    """
    A levels 'bounds' refers to the number of the first folder and the last folder
    on that level. For example, when r == 2, and the level == 3, the
    bounds is (4, 7). The smallest possible level is 1, which, for any
    value of r always returns (1, 1).
    """
    assert(level > 0, "Smallest possible level is 1.")
    if level == 1:
        return 1, 1
    else:
        lower = sumOfProgression(foldersPerFolder, level-1) + 1
        upper = lower + pow(foldersPerFolder, level-1) - 1
        return lower, upper


def ancestorsOfFolder(folder, ancestors):
    """ Find the shortest route from folder '1' for the specified folder value.

    On completion, ancestors will contain a list of numbers each of which
    represents a folder in the ancestral line of 'folder'. The first number in
    the list will always be 'folder' and the last number will always be 1."""
    # First get the level...
    level = findLevelOfFolder(folder)
    lowerBoundOfPreviousLevel, _ = boundsOfLevel(level-1)

    relativePosition = folder - sumOfProgression(foldersPerFolder, level-1)
    parent = (lowerBoundOfPreviousLevel - 1) + math.ceil(relativePosition/foldersPerFolder)
    ancestors.append(parent)
    if parent != 1:
        ancestorsOfFolder(parent, ancestors)

# 'r' value
foldersPerFolder = 2

# looking for ancestral line of...
folder = 23

print(ancestorsOfFolder(folder, [folder])) # -> [23, 11, 5, 2, 1]
```

Comment: Shouldn't the ancestral line for `26` be `[26, 13, 6, 3, 1]`, not 15?

Comment: What do you mean "created by geometric progression"? Do you mean the number of children of each non-leaf is `r`?

Comment: @Brent Washburne: it should - I've made the edit.

Comment: @G. Bach: yes - it's a file tree, so each folder will contain ``r`` folders (as well as some files).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pattern is easier to see if you start by numbering the root as 0.

For r = 4:

```
              0
     1     2        3      4
   5..8  9..12  13..16   17..20
```

In this case, each node `k` would have `floor((k-1)/r)` as its parent.

If you start the numbering at 1, though, as in

```
              1
     2     3        4      5
   6..9  10..13  14..17   18..21
```

it gets a little messier. You need to subtract *something* before dividing by `4`, then add *something else* back. What those somethings are is not immediately clear to me. My advice: work with a 0-based tree if possible :)

Comment: This pattern is correct. One way to prove it would be to inductively show what indices the *children* of a node have, then invert the formula.

Comment: Subtract 2 before dividing by `r`, then add 1

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - have switched to zero-based tree and got things working well.

Answer (score 1):

Third time's the charm (third edit, anyway).

The parent at each level can be found with the equation `folder = (folder - 2) // r + 1`:

```
def ancestorsOfFolder(folder, r):
    ancestors = []
    while folder > 0:
        ancestors.append(folder)
        folder = (folder - 2) // r + 1
    return ancestors
```

EDIT: I agree, using a zero-based tree is preferable.  The parents can be found with the equation `folder = (folder - 1) // r`.  Here is the code:

```
def ancestorsOfFolder(folder, r):
    ancestors = []
    while folder > 0:
        ancestors.append(folder)
        folder = (folder - 1) // r
    ancestors.append(0)
    return ancestors
```

Comment: This works for `r=2`; in general, it's a bit messier.

Comment: Dividing by 2 and rounding down works well when ``r = 2`` but I'm looking for a general solution. That said the principle of dividing by ``r`` looks promising (embarrassed that I didn't see it myself), I just need to work out when to round up and when to round down. For example when ``r = 5`` the parent of folder ``32`` and folder ``36`` is folder ``7`` but in the former case I have to round up after dividing by ``r`` to get this number, whereas in the latter I round down.

Comment: Added a line to adjust the folder number at each level, accounting for the variable `r`

Comment: This still doesn't work. For example, for r=3, it says that 2 is an ancestor of 4.

Comment: Third edit for the equation is provided in the answer

Comment: Thanks for the effort put in here. I've taken the advice of chepner and gone with a zero-based tree, so marked his as the accepted answer.